# PHP Scraping Page

Tags: php, dom, xpath, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a page where the information I'm looking for lies within:

```
 <tr class="defRowEven">
   <td align="right">label</td>
   <td>info</td>
 </tr>
```

I'm trying to get the label and info out of the page. Before I was doing something like:

```
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");
```

That is how I'm grabbing the URL's. Is there a way to grab that `tr` information? Would it be better to use regex or using the `DOMXPath`? I'm very unfamiliar with `DOMXPath` and any information would be more than helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with xpath, but using [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) you can do this:

```
foreach($html->find('tr.defRowEven') as $row) {

    //get the 'label' (first cell)
    echo $row->find('td', 0)->innerText;

    //get the 'info' (second cell)
    echo $row->find('td', 1)->innerText;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, no luck. Just a blank screen. I'll keep working with the class though, Thank you!

Comment: @Frederico - maybe try echo $row->find('td', 0)->plainText; instead

Answer (score 4):

XPath can select based on attributes.  To find your row, then, use:

```
$rows = $xpath->query("//tr[@class='defRowEven']");
```

This should return a list of rows, so you can select the label and info for each without mixing them up:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $label = $xpath->evaluate("td[@align='right']", $row);
    $info = $xpath->evaluate("td[2]", $row);
}
```

In case that doesn't work out, you can try the regex route:

```
preg_match_all('/<tr class="defRowEven">\s*<td align="right">(.*?)<\/td>\s*<td>(.*?)<\/td>/',
    $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    list($full, $label, $info) = $match;
}
```

Comment: Tried your 2nd example, and couldn't get that working. I'll keep trying though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Someone here recently at SO gave a link to [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) .. a kind of jQuery for php/server-side .. which SHOULD make this kinda thing easy. I've not tried it so can't comment first hand